# Fusion Tables API: How do I make a PUT request to update a style via Ruby, JavaScript, or other languages?

Tags: php, javascript, python, ruby, google-fusion-tables

I was looking at [this Fusion Tables API page](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/reference/style/update) on how to update a Fusion Table's style settings via the Fusion Tables API.

Apparently, you must make a PUT request in order to update the Fusion Table's style.

I was wondering: How do I do that in Ruby or JavaScript? And is it possible to do it in other popular languages (e.g., pHp, Python)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python you can easily perform a PUT HTTP request using the Requests module.

```
import requests

key = u'your_api_key'
url = u'https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/tables/tableId/styles/styleId?key=%s' % key

body = dict()
body[u'markerOptions.iconName'] = u'geographic_features'
# put other settings here

r = request.put(url, data=body)
```

Requests documentation can be found here : http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 1):

Not a *'popular language'* but very useful :)

```
curl -X POST https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/tables/XXX/styles/XXX
```